# Как выбрать строки, в которых хотя бы одно значение из списка есть в массиве?

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице `table` есть поле `column`, которая является массивом чисел. Как мне выбрать все строки в таблице, в которых встречается хотя бы одно из значений списка `(1, 2, 3)`?

Если бы значение было одно, то я бы сделал это так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = ANY(column)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where column && array[1,2,3]
```

[Оператор `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) для массивов - `overlap (have elements in common)`, возвращает истину если у двух массивов есть хотя бы один общий элемент. Ровно то что вам необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

Будет что-то типа

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3])
       INTERSECT
       SELECT UNNEST(column)) IS NOT NULL
```